# No success message is being displayed, when user clicks on submit (to get applied to the newsletter)

Tags: jquery, html, css, shopify, liquid

I've been struggling with this problem for quite some hours now, I'm using shopify with the 'debut' theme. it does work when I make a new account and just leave everything ontouched, but I've made a lot of changes to my own code and it messes everything up. When a user clicks on the "submit" button normally there should be a message saying something, but in my case it doesn't show any message, it does load onto my e-mailing list. So the customer_posted=true#ContactFooter is working but it simply doesn't show the message which I really want.

I've tried to analyse the code from a new theme and apply it, but it simply doesn't work or loads at all, I guess I'm missing some jQuery or some sort, the contact form works perfectly, I'm confused because I archive my daily goals and it messes with my head if I don't finish it soon. Thanks for reading.

(the newsletter function is added to the footer-page which is standard) I will apply the code from the footer section and the newsletter, everything is in .liquid since its shopify.

This is footer.liquid with some simple `.css`:

```
<div class="site-footer__newsletter">
    <form method="post"action="/contact#ContactFooter" 
          id="ContactFooter" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="contact-form" novalidate="novalidate">
        <input type="hidden" name="form_type" value="customer"><input type="hidden" name="utf8" value="✓">
        <input type="hidden" name="contact[tags]" value="newsletter">
        <div class="input-group ">
            <input type="email" name="contact[email]" 
                   id="ContactFooter-email" 
                   class="input-group__field newsletter__input" 
                   value="" 
                   placeholder="E-mailadres" 
                   aria-label="E-mailadres" 
                   aria-required="true" 
                   required="" 
                   autocorrect="off" 
                   autocapitalize="off">
                  <span class="input-group__btn">
                    <button type="submit" 
                            class="btn newsletter__submit" 
                            name="commit" 
                            id="Subscribe" style="border-radius: 6px;">
                      <span class="newsletter__submit-text--large">{{ 'general.newsletter_form.submit' | t }}</span>
```

**Newsletter.liquid**

```
{% if form.posted_successfully? %}
  <p class="form--success">{{ 'general.newsletter_form.confirmation' | t }}</p>
{% else %}
   <div class="input-group password__input-group">
    <input type="hidden" name="contact[tags]" value="newsletter">
    <input type="email"
      name="contact[email]"
      id="Email"
      class="input-group__field newsletter__input omnisend-subscribe-input-email"
      value="{% if customer %}{{ customer.email }}{% endif %}"
      placeholder="{{ 'general.newsletter_form.email_placeholder' | t }}"
      autocorrect="off"
      autocapitalize="off">
```

{{ 'general.newsletter_form.submit' | t }}
          
        
      
    {% endif %}

Codepen: https://codepen.io/Tendiasx112/pen/XWJpOYb?&editable=true  (but it has no scripts working)

Comment: I've edited the most part that didn't seem relevant, I hardly ask for help though, I always try to figure out things myself, but I'm not sure how to search for the part that does that exactly, after the submit supplication: it only displays this: customer_posted=true#ContactFooter without a message but the e-mail address is added to my mailing list. I can give you my website and password if you would like, there's a lot of code though

Comment: Would you please give link to the store?
Because the line: <p class="form--success">{{ 'general.newsletter_form.confirmation' | t }}</p> should display when form has been submitted.

Comment: @AliceGirard that would be really appreciated, how can I contact you ?

Comment: I've successfully fixed it myself. Please close this thread.